# How to run a specific test file in Karma? (Angular 4+)

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

When I run `ng test`, it goes through all test files.

I found an answer, by running the providing the path of the file:

```
ng test --main src/app/pages/home-modal/home-modal.component.spec.ts
```

on stackoverflow but I guess it was deprecated and I received this error:

***AsyncTestZoneSpec is needed for the async()***

Here is my karma.config.ts file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });

};
```

**Does anyone know the new way of running a specific file in Karma for Angular 4+?**

Answer (score 4):

To run a single test file, change the `describe` block in the file to `fdescribe` and run the tests as usual using `ng test`.

You can also use `fit` to run a single test case alone.

Comment: how do I do that in my test file?

Comment: If you open your test file (`home-modal.component.spec.ts`), there will be a `describe` block inside which all test cases are written. Change it to `fdescribe`. Run `ng test` and now only the `home-modal.component.spec.ts` tests will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In your `test.ts` file you should have a line for

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

That last part of `/\.spec\.ts$/` is regex for load any find that ends with `.spec.ts`.

You can change this (temporarily) to be `/your\.component\.spec\.ts$/` and then run `npm test` as normal